# Python has stopped Working on using pyttsx3

Tags: python, pyttsx3

I am just trying to a python module 'pyttsx3' and got this error "Python has Stopped Working".
The code is all correct. Please anyone help me in fixing this..[enter image description here]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk62k.png)

I have tried restarting my computer, updating python, using the command prompt but nothing worked.

Comment: Hi, user19237525!  Right now, there isn't enough information in your question for us to help you.  Is the problem only happening when you try to run code using the `pyttsx3` module, or has Python stopped working for you in all cases?  Did you get any other error messages before you saw that error popup, and did they have a more specific reason?  If it's only trying to run specific code that's causing this problem, please add the problem code to your answer (see Stack Overflow's guidelines on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)